# How do you Find Linear Mileage?

Tags: arcgis-9.3

I have never done this before, but how do you find the linear mileage of microseismic lines?  I tried researching it online in different forums/tutorials with no luck. I have ArcView 9.3, no other extensions.  I went into the Toolbox Linear Referencing Box and from there, I tried a few of the tools, but no luck.

This is for PostPlot source points (Microseismic survey). Simply put, as above, I need to find the linear mileage with the postplot points that goes on/through the surface owners.  How do I do this?

Be advised, I am not a programmer nor a techie.  If at all possible, keep any answers as simple as possible unless it is unavoidable.

If you need more information, please let me know as I did my best to provide pertinent information.

### I have included a pdf of the data if this helps any.

A cheap and easy way to do this is use the Measure Tool.  But, I figure that HAS TO BE A better way to do it then individually for each parcel.  Is there?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a one row sample of your survey data? It sounds like you need to utilize the point data to create linear equivalent and then calculate miles.

Comment: Brad, is there anyway we can IM or realtime communicate as this linear mileage is brand new to me.  I don't know if I have the extensions necassary for it. 

Do I need spatial analysis?

Answer (score 3):

I have to apologise.  I'm not entirely certain I understand what you're trying to do.  If you just need distances, you can simply digitize as you need to, and use the [Calculate Geometry function.](http://www.lib.uoguelph.ca/resources/data_resource_centre/help_&_learning_resources/geospatial_help/components/documents/calculatingarea.pdf)  Capture polylines through the points at the distances you want to measure, add a field for your distances, and use the function outlined at the link I posted above.

Give it a quick read.  This might be your answer.

**Edit in response to your comment below:**

Zoran.  Calculate Geometry should work (or I'm not understanding what you're trying to do).  If you see the images below----> **In screen 1**, I have added a field to house the calculations.  I right mouse on the new field, and select calculate geometry, it will bring up screen 2. ------> **in screen 2**, you can see "AREA" is an option in the first dropdown (Beside "**PROPERTY**").  You can pick almost anything under there relevant to the geometry of the shapefile you're working with (hectares, square metres, linear feet, metres, etc, etc).  As long as it's a spatial file (shapefile, etc) and you're in a coordinate system that allows accurate area/length calculations, this should work just fine.  Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish, but there should be other options besides **JUST** calculating the X & Y coordinates using this command.  That's all I've got for you.  I hope it solves your issue.

[image: Command Location]

[image: Calc options]

Comment: Dano - I tried that but it would only calculate the X and Y Coordinates.  
------------
Ok, with the pdf/graph, the dots are the postplots/cables (geophones)layed out... I am needing the acreage of those dots/postplots for each parcel.  Not just of the individual "dots" but a continious line (imaginary line going from point to point) as those are the cables layed down.  The dots are the geophones. 

I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: @Zoran - See edit above

Answer (score 2):

Since the only software you are trying to use is (arcview) 9.3 you will need to do several things.
1. Convert the records to points.
2. convert the points to lines.
3  set the document crs so that you can calculate miles.

I'll explain the needs in each step.

you have what loooks like an electronic spreadsheeet of the data.
You will need to format that so that it is in row form.
(that is each row represents a specific point) You can include the column headings as you have above.
however it should be one continuos row all the way across.
 I realize you probably just formatted the pdf for display. just trying to be clear.

To me it looks like the best value to place points with would be the local easting/northing values.
the lat lon values are ony 2 decimals you need at least 6 to get any accuracy, and as you have local easting (looks like meters?) that would be good.
When you add the spreadsheet (or csv) to arcgis you will right click on the table.
(you can find the table by swithing the TOC to data mode)
Select "display xy data" in the right click flyout.
Now you will be presented with a dialog showing 2 fields which you can modify (Plus a z if you are interested).
choose the localeasting (probably will be truncated to 8 chars) as the x value, and localnorthing as the y. Set the CRS to predefined> GCS> World> WGS84 as the projection.
Now I would export that data to a shapefile...
Right click data> export. choose a folder (make sure you know where)
you can say yes to add it to the map.

Now Unless you have some other tools to use you will probably have to manually connect all the points.
I think et-tools has something for free
Something you said made me think you only want the total length of a siesmic line in a polygon.
So you will need to break each line at the intersection of the polygon edge.
Actually on re-read you will need to decide what lengtht\ it is you are looking for.
the length at each point or just a total length in each polygon.
If the sec cond is true create a line goinng through each point (use snap) and break (split) each one at th epolygon edge.
If the first condition is tru you will need to break the line at each point.

Next you should set your project crs to a unit that can be connverted to miles. (feet preferable). Make sure that you have a field (double 0,0) in your shape file called length.
Add a new field called len_mile (double 0,0)

Right click and calculate geometry on the length field.
NOTE: you can only calculate decimal degrees or the units of the active data frame CRS. (which you just set to feet.)
Select that option.
Now you should have feet in your length field.
Now right click on the len_mile field and select field calculator.
now select the length field and add it to the expression, with / 5280
select ok and you should end up with decimal miles in the len_mile field.
If you need to display miles in easy to read terms you can use the
(Round [len_mile], 2) 
Function. This will not change the value but display it with 2 decimals.

HTH

Comment: Ok..I will try that later today and let you know the results.